# CartoDB: custom sorting infowindow entries

Tags: carto

I am trying to create a visualization at runtime like explained in the [Cartodb documentation](http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html#runtime):
Then I add infowindows for each entry with this command:

```
cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, layer.getSubLayer(0),  
 ['center_name','phone','age_range']);
```

But the entries are displayed in alphabetical order, not the order I want it to be. Is there any way to force it to keep my order?

Comment: could you provide an example of this? fields are sort by order https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/src/vis/vis.js#L1012

Comment: Here is the [map online](http://childcaremap.github.io/NYCdaycare/dev/createmap.html) and here is [the code](https://github.com/childcaremap/NYCdaycare/blob/gh-pages/dev/createmap.html). I specify the field in order: 'center_name','phone','age_range' but they appear in the infowindow as: "Age Range", "Center Name" and "Phone".

Comment: I've just fixed the problem: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/issues/126 You can use the development version while we release a the new version: http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.10.2-dev/cartodb.js

Answer (score 1):

As it's said in the comments, this was an issue in the CartoDB.js library that was fixed according to this [GitHub issue of their repo](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/issues/126).